# R: format the output of `warning()` for a list of options over more than one line

Tags: r, error-handling

I'm writing error handling steps for an R function that fails to find the right match to a query, so presents users with a list of options.  I have the output of potential matches in a list, and I'd like the warning to format this as a numbered list:

```
'multiple matches for query "Tom", select which one you want:'
 [1] Tom Bombadil
 [2] Tom Overhill
 [3] Justanother Tom
```

Unfortunately, warning and message seem to like removing linebreaks.  For instance, if I have:

```
opts <- list("Tom Bombadil", "Tom Overhill", "Justanother Tom")
```

The command

```
warning(opts)
```

prints:

```
Warning message:
Tom BombadilTom OverhillJustanother Tom
```

How do I get this into the format I'd like from above (ideally with numbers so I can capture the number choice from `readLines`)

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about this:

```
select.list(c("Tom Bombadil", "Tom Overhill", "Justanother Tom"),
              title = "Multiple matches for query \"Tom\", 
                       select which one you want:")
Multiple matches for query "Tom", select which one you want: 

1: Tom Bombadil
2: Tom Overhill
3: Justanother Tom

Selection: 2
[1] "Tom Overhill"
```

Comment: Excellent solution, solves my formatting question and captures the user selection issue!  Note to posterity: to simply format `warning` or `message` over multiple lines, I believe `paste0` was the function I was looking for (with `collapse="\n")`